# PHP find function without found element html

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to grab the string inside H1 without actually H1 inside the string.

```
$html = "<div id="test"><h1>hello world</h1></div>"


foreach($html->find('div[id=test] h1') as $test1){
        echo '<div>';
        echo $test1;
        echo '</div>';
}

$test1 returns "<h1>hello world</h1>"
```

I'd like for $test1 to be just "hello world" and without the h1 tags.  Thank you in advance

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid PHP at all.

Comment: `echo "<h1>".strip_tags("<div id="test"><h1>hello world</h1></div>")."</h1>";`

Comment: Ahh, strip tags. Thank you so much! 
    echo strip_tags($test1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex for this:

```
$str = '<div id="test"><h1>hello world</h1></div>';
$matches = array();
preg_match('/<h1>(.*)<\/h1>/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Outputs: `hello world`

> Docs:

- http://www.php.net/preg_match

> Demos:

- https://eval.in/78867
- http://regex101.com/r/lG3dO8

Comment: I like this answer, however, strip tags works well for me too. Thank you for answering